# how could I set the cell style in a column in a datagrid dynamically with converter or datatrigger?

Tags: wpf

I would like to set dynamically the style of a row in a column of a datagrid according to a data in the data row, so according to the value of that property, only one property, I would like to choose between 3 different styles that I have in a resource dictionary.

I am trying this solution:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridCellLeftHorizontalAlignment}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumeroLineaFactura}" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

But this has the problem that I can only select the one of the styles and I have to change the rest of the properties one by one, so how I have to set the style in various columns, it makes me to repeat the code.

I would like to can select the style with a data trigger or with a converter, but I don't know the syntax to can do it, because in the trigger I can set the property Style neither CellStryle.

How could I set the cell style dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the property that you want to use to determine which style to used defined in the view model or the data "row" object?

Comment: in the data row object, is NumeriLineaFactura.

Comment: What differs between the different styles?

Comment: Basics differences are font weight and alignement of the text (left or right). So My idea it was to have diferent styles and select the style according to the data row property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no `CellStyleSelector` property available and you cannot use a `DataTrigger` to change the `Style` itself, you should use a single `Style` and then use several `DataTriggers` to change the properties of the `DataGridCell`, e.g.:

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumeroLineaFactura}" Value="-1">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

> Thanks. In this case it works, but if I have another column that for the -1 value has the same style, I have to repeat the code...

Right. In this case you could consider implementing your own custom DataGridTextColumn and programmatically set the `CellStyle`. Something like this:

```
public class CustomDataGridTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        name: nameof(FirstStyle),
        propertyType: typeof(Style),
        ownerType: typeof(CustomDataGridTextColumn)));

    public Style FirstStyle
    {
        get => (Style)GetValue(FirstStyleProperty);
        set => SetValue(FirstStyleProperty, value);
    }

    //...

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);

        var val = dataItem as YourClass;
        if(val != null)
        {
            switch (val.NumeroLineaFactura)
            {
                case -1:
                    cell.Style = FirstStyle;
                    break;
                //...
            }
        }

        return element;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <local:CustomDataGridTextColumn ... FirstStyle="{StaticResource yourFirstStyle}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case it works, but if I have another column that for the -1 value has the same style, I have to repeat the code. So if I could have a style for the case of -1 and apply when I need, it would need less code.

Comment: Then you need to implement a solution yourself. See my edit for an example.